# Execute a method when the textbox's text is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

There are these text boxes in my interface:

[image]

where the Total and Change boxes are readonly.
My question is, how do I execute a method to calculate the change as the user types in the payment?

The bounded Payment textbox is this:

```
private decimal _cartPayment;
public decimal CartPayment {
    get { return _cartPayment; }
    set { 
    _cartPayment = value;
    //this.NotifyPropertyChanged("CartPayment");
    }
}
```

And my XAML is as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CartPayment, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

My ViewModel has `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here

Comment: This might help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx

Comment: @goodfriend, tagged with WPF, not Winforms

Comment: Oh, but the method is same so. Well sorry for the link :|

Comment: If the Change textbox has a binding to a dependency property, lets say `ChangeValue`, all you need to do is alter `ChangeValue` when `_cartPayment` changes and the View will update automatically. Thats the point of binding, right?

Comment: @Jodrell why don't u write him an answer if u know why is everything else wrong?

Comment: @goodfriend, knowing that MVVM is not supposed to use event handlers doesn't mean I know exactly what the right answer is. If I did, I would submit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take advantage of UpdateSourceTrigger. You can modify your code like

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CartPayment, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

and your property like

```
private decimal _cartPayment;
public decimal CartPayment
{
get { return _cartPayment; }
set 
 { 
  _cartPayment = value;
  // call your required
  // method here
  this.NotifyPropertyChanged("CartPayment");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is an MVVM approach that doesn't hack any properties' get/set:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CartPayment, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ComputeNewPriceCommand}" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

`xmlns:i` being the `System.Windows.Interactivity` namespace in xaml
ComputeNewPriceCommand being any kind of ICommand that points to your recalculation method.

Comment: nowadays its `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"` and the nuGet package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is add to your `Binding` `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. By default object will be updated when control looses focus to save time.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar within my application, but calculates the number of days left.

You could try something like the following;

```
//Create a new class
public class ConreteAdder : IAdder
{
    public decimal Add(decimal total,decimal payment)
    {
        return total - payment; //What ever method or mathematical solution you want
    }
}

public interface IAdder
{
    decimal Add(decimal total, decimal payment);
}
```

Then, within your VM, implement the following;

```
    private readonly IAdder _adder = new ConreteAdder();
    private void NumberChanged() //Call this method within the properties you want to create the mathematical equation with
    {
        Change = _adder.Add(Payment, Total); //Or whatever method you want
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged2;

    private void OnResultChanged()
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged2;
        if (handler == null) return;
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Result"));
    }
```

Then, within your properties, just call either one of the two methods. 
for example;

```
public decimal CartPayment 
{
get { return _cartPayment; }
set 
{ 
    _cartPayment = value;
    OnResultChanged(); //propertychanged event handler called
    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("CartPayment");
}
}
```

Within your xaml like so;

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CartPayment,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Hope this helps! :)

*EDIT*: Take a look at the [Following link](http://davesquared.net/2010/02/attempt-at-simple-mvvm-with-wpf.html). This may help you further.